# Populating Networkx Graph with info iteratively

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges

I have been trying to develop a graph structure that will link entities according to co-mentioned features between them, e.g. 2 places are linked if co-mentioned in an article.

I have managed to do so but I have been having problems to iteratively populate an edge with new information keeping the already existing one.

My approach (since I haven't found anything related anywhere) is to append existing information to a list, append the new link in the list and assign that list to the appropriate feature.

```
    temp = []
    if G.has_edge(i[z],i[j]):
        temp.append(G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'])
        temp.append(url[index])
        G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'] = temp
    else:
        print "Create edge!"
        G.add_edge(i[z],i[j], article=url)
    del temp[:]
```

As you can see above, as there are many links to be populated, I defined a dedicated list (temp), loaded the old contents of a link's variable called article (if the link does not exist I create a link and add as first value the url that "brought" 2 places together.

My problem is that while I empty the list each time in order to be empty when a new pair comes in when I try to see a link's urls I get something like this:

```
{'article': [[...], u'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/.../']
```

It seems like I am keeping only the last link as each time I delete the temporary list's contents but I cannot find a better way to do so without declaring an unnecessary bunch of temp lists.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL/DR summary: change your entire snippet to

```
if G.has_edge(i[z],i[j]):
        G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'].append(url[index])
    else:
        G.add_edge(i[z],i[j], article=[url])
```

---

Here's what's going on:

When you create the edge the first time you use

```
G.add_edge(i[z],i[j], article=url)
```

So it's a string.  But later when you do

```
G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'] = temp
```

you've defined `temp` to be a list whose first element is `G[i[z]][i[j]]['article']`.  So `G[i[z]][i[j]]['article']` is now a list with two elements, the first of which is the old value for `G[i[z]][i[j]]['article']` (a string) and the second of which is the new url (also a string).

Your problem comes at the later steps:

From then on, it's exactly the same thing.  `G[i[z]][i[j]]['article']` is again a list with two elements, the first of which is its old value (a list) and the second is the new url (a string).  So you've got a nested list.

let's trace through with three urls: `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`, and I'll use `E` to abbreviate `G[i[z]][i[j]]`.  First time through, you get `E='a'`.  Second time through you get `E=['a', 'b']`.  Third time through it gives `E=[['a','b'],'c']`.  So it's always making `E[0]` to be the former value of `E`, and `E[1]` to be the new url.

Two choices:

1) you can handle the creation of `temp` differently if you've got a string or a list.  This is the bad choice.

2)Better: Make it a list the whole time through and then don't even deal with `temp`.  Try creating the edge as `(...,article = [url])` and then just use `G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'].append(url)` instead of defining `temp`.

So your code would be

```
if G.has_edge(i[z],i[j]):
        G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'].append(url[index])
    else:
        G.add_edge(i[z],i[j], article=[url])
```

---

A separate thing that could also cause you problems is the call

```
del temp[:]
```

This should cause behavior different from what I think you're describing.  So I think this is a bit different from how it's actually coded.  When you set `G[i[z]][i[j]] = temp` and then do `del temp[:]`, you've made the two lists to be one list with two different names.  When you `del temp[:]` you're also doing it to `G[i[z]][i[j]]`.  Consider the following

```
temp = []
temp.append(1)
print temp
> [1]    
L = temp
print L
> [1]
del temp[:]
print L
> []
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going to try your suggested way now and let you know but my gut says that the first problem I need to solve is the del temp[:]. I thought it was permitted to use a list as a wildcard and add info to the graph links.

Comment: If you use what I've suggested, temp won't even be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think all your previous URLs are in your new list. They are in the [...].

You must use extend instead of append when you get the existing list from the edge.

```
temp = []
temp.append([1, 2, 3])
temp.append(1)
print(temp)
```

You will get:

```
[[1, 2, 3], 4]
```

But if you do:

```
temp = []
temp.extend([1, 2, 3])
temp.append(4)
print(temp)
```

You get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I do not think that is the case since when I try to get all urls of a specific edge I am getting:
    [[...], u'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/.../'] again. If I use extend when adding a URL as you proposed it will return ['h','t','t','p'...] instead of ['http://www...']

Comment: What if you do G[i[z]][i[j]]['article'].append(url[index]) instead of creating a temporary list ?

Comment: I tried that just to make sure but as I suspected : AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'.

Comment: The reason for this `AttributeError` is that the first time through it's a string, while the second time through it's a list.  It should be a consistent data type throughout.  Make it a list when you first create it.